# How to limit a query to only the most recent occurence in Access

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have three tables: Employees, Trainings, & TrainingSessions

I have a query that pulls LastName and FirstName from the Employees table, it pulls TrainingTitle and SessionDate from the TrainingSessions table, it also has an expression that calculates that date a renewal training is due.

Trainings can be completed multiple times but I only want information on the most recent occurrence of any individual training. How do I limit the list to only the most recent occurrence.

I'm just learning Access so please explain in the simplest terms possible. If you need more information, I'd be glad to provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do MAX in a separate query on the renewal date column.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT TOP n column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC`

where *n* is the number of rows to return and *column* is the name of the relevant column and *table* is the name of the database table.

Hope it helps,

Avi.

Comment: OK, mayby it's because I have very little idea what I'm doing here, but:

1. I don't understand how to input that so it is in the correct location.

2. How would I determine the correct number for "n" when there are multiple employee names, multiple training titles and multiple occurences of trainings which will vary by each employee.

Comment: If you are asking me to provide you with the exact SQL statement that you need, you need to provide more information, including the structure of the database tables and a sample of the output you expect to see.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help!